# Trying to convert an Excel Macro over to standalone VBScript

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript

I have the following macro that works perfectly within Excel but I know absolutly nothing about vbscripting other than what it has in common with vba. I have tried a few things and no longer get errors but it still does not function. The purpose of the code is to open an excel sheet full of inspection data and turn the cells Red, Amber, Or Green depending on if the feature is in out of tolerance, using > 80% of its tolerance, or in tolerance. Within excel this will loop for all files selected in the fDialog and i would like to keep that functionality if possible.

```
'#================================================================================
'# MakeRAG.vbs                                                                   |
'#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'#                                                                               |
'# Function:-                                                                    |
'#     Script will convert standard crystal reports in .xlsx format to RAG Charts|
'# Parameters:-                                                                  |
'#     none                                                                      |
'# Returns:-                                                                     |
'#     nothing                                                                   |
'#================================================================================
'# +---------+----------+---------------------------------------+----------------+
'# | Version |   Date   |        Changes                        |       By       |
'# |   1.00  | 11/02/20 |First Release                          | -------------- |
'# |         |          |                                       |                |
'# |         |          |                                       |                |
'# +---------+----------+---------------------------------------+----------------+
'#================================================================================
Option Explicit
Sub Main()
'
Dim i 'As Integer
Dim j 'As Integer
Dim nominal 'As Double
Dim upperTol 'As Double
Dim lowerTol 'As Double
Dim upperAmber 'As Double
Dim lowerAmber 'As Double
Dim amberPercent 'As Double
Dim fDialog 'As FileDialog
Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

Dim thing 'As Variant
Dim xl 'As Excel.Application
Dim ragChart 'As Excel.Workbook
amberPercent = 0.8  'Feature will show as amber if exceeding this percent of tolerance

Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

With fDialog
    .AllowMultiSelect = True
    .Title = "Select files to make into RAG Charts"
    .InitialFileName = "C:\"
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xlsx"
End With

If fDialog.Show = -1 Then
    'Loop through all files selected in the File Open Dialog
    For Each thing In fDialog.SelectedItems
        'Open Workbook
        Set ragChart = xl.Workbooks.Open(thing)
        With ragChart.Sheets(1)
            'Loop through all columns starting at column 5
            For i = 5 To Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range("A3").EntireRow)
                nominal = Cells(5, i).Value
                upperTol = Cells(4, i).Value
                lowerTol = Cells(6, i).Value
                upperAmber = nominal + ((upperTol - nominal) * amberPercent)
                lowerAmber = nominal - ((nominal - lowerTol) * amberPercent)
                'Loop through all rows in current column
                For j = 7 To Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range("B7").EntireColumn) + 7
                    If Cells(j, i).Value = "" Then
                        Cells(j, i).Interior.Color = xlNone
                    ElseIf Cells(j, i).Value > upperTol Or Cells(j, i).Value < lowerTol Then
                        Cells(j, i).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                    ElseIf Cells(j, i).Value > upperAmber Or Cells(j, i).Value < lowerAmber Then
                        Cells(j, i).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 191, 0)
                    Else
                        Cells(j, i).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
                    End If
                Next' j
            Next' i
        End With
        'Save and close Workbook
        ragChart.Save
        ragChart.Quit
    Next' thing
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VBScript does not have a host application, and does not know about these Excel objects you are referenceing, and other issues

- The main routine of a script isn't encapsulated in a `Sub` - delete it
- Named Constants arn't known `msoFileDialogFilePicker`, `xlNone` - use their values instead
- `Application` isn't known - use the `xl` instance you already created
- `Cells` isn't known - use the `With` block you already created (this is an issue in your VBA too)
- You must ceate the `xl` instance before you access it - `Set xl ...` goes before `Set fDialog ...`
- You can't `Quit` a workbook - `Close` it
- You may want to `Quit` the `xl` object at the end

I'll take you at your word that *macro that works perfectly within Excel*, as I can't see your sheet (but it looks a bit fragile to me)

```
Option Explicit

Dim i 'As Integer
Dim j 'As Integer
Dim nominal 'As Double
Dim upperTol 'As Double
Dim lowerTol 'As Double
Dim upperAmber 'As Double
Dim lowerAmber 'As Double
Dim amberPercent 'As Double
Dim fDialog 'As FileDialog

Dim thing 'As Variant
Dim xl 'As Excel.Application
Dim ragChart 'As Excel.Workbook

amberPercent = 0.8  'Feature will show as amber if exceeding this percent of tolerance

Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set fDialog = xl.FileDialog(3)

With fDialog
    .AllowMultiSelect = True
    .Title = "Select files to make into RAG Charts"
    .InitialFileName = "C:\"
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xlsx"
End With

If fDialog.Show = -1 Then
    'Loop through all files selected in the File Open Dialog
    For Each thing In fDialog.SelectedItems
        'Open Workbook
        Set ragChart = xl.Workbooks.Open(thing)
        With ragChart.Sheets(1)
            'Loop through all columns starting at column 5
            For i = 5 To xl.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range("A3").EntireRow)
                nominal = .Cells(5, i).Value
                upperTol = .Cells(4, i).Value
                lowerTol = .Cells(6, i).Value
                upperAmber = nominal + ((upperTol - nominal) * amberPercent)
                lowerAmber = nominal - ((nominal - lowerTol) * amberPercent)
                'Loop through all rows in current column
                For j = 7 To xl.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range("B7").EntireColumn) + 7
                    If .Cells(j, i).Value = "" Then
                        .Cells(j, i).Interior.Color = -4142
                    ElseIf .Cells(j, i).Value > upperTol Or .Cells(j, i).Value < lowerTol Then
                        .Cells(j, i).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                    ElseIf .Cells(j, i).Value > upperAmber Or .Cells(j, i).Value < lowerAmber Then
                        .Cells(j, i).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 191, 0)
                    Else
                        .Cells(j, i).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
                    End If
                Next ' j
            Next ' i
        End With
        'Save and close Workbook
        ragChart.Close True
    Next ' thing
End If
xl.Quit
```

Comment: Holy cow... this is dedication to lay out that list of issues :-)

Comment: Thank You! This is my first experience working with a vbscript. I got into the habit of using .quit when access kept leaving excel processes open in the background. Unfortunately due to sensitive data I was unable to include a workbook example. Finally, you are correct, everything I write is fragile. Only when I’m done do I find a better way